# RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument while specifying packet loss by tc command

Tags: linux, networking, tc, packetloss, openvswitch

I am trying to specify packet loss by tc command on interface (port) 1 of switch part of network I have created using mininet : 
`sudo tc qdisc change dev s1-eth1 root netem loss 0.1%`
but gettring error:
**`RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`**

Any help would be appreciated

**Network Details:**

It is a tree topology based mininet network on Ubuntu 14.04 with depth = 2 and fanout = 5. On first level, a switch is connected to 5 switches which are connected to 5 hosts each. All switches are OpenvSwitch.

**Other details that MAY be required:**

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:bc:12:57:a2:25  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::fabc:12ff:fe57:a225/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:373 errors:0 dropped:371 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:70350 (70.3 KB)  TX bytes:14244 (14.2 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:36:02:e1  
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe36:2e1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:47853 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25038783 (25.0 MB)  TX bytes:6855972 (6.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:91530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:91530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:17283542 (17.2 MB)  TX bytes:17283542 (17.2 MB)

s1        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:d6:3f:00:7e:4c  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c80a:80ff:fef9:446/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:748 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:127789 (127.7 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

s2        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 96:44:d2:f0:2d:41  
          inet6 addr: fe80::90d6:48ff:fed5:4f06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:126441 (126.4 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

s3        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:fa:d0:0f:03:41  
          inet6 addr: fe80::b04e:e2ff:fee8:2b83/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:748 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:127813 (127.8 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

s4        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:37:27:fe:63:40  
          inet6 addr: fe80::dc77:94ff:fe7f:20d3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:128003 (128.0 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

s5        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:69:62:24:87:47  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e0da:a3ff:fe72:34d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:127945 (127.9 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

s6        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9a:f8:f6:55:22:43  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc44:bdff:fe7c:e15a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:732 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:127241 (127.2 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

s1-eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 32:d3:9d:d3:d4:bc  
          inet6 addr: fe80::30d3:9dff:fed3:d4bc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26351 (26.3 KB)  TX bytes:126071 (126.0 KB)

s1-eth2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:b0:08:e5:69:9e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::74b0:8ff:fee5:699e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:732 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26921 (26.9 KB)  TX bytes:126873 (126.8 KB)

s1-eth3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b2:81:d3:9c:56:50  
          inet6 addr: fe80::b081:d3ff:fe9c:5650/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:709 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27595 (27.5 KB)  TX bytes:125363 (125.3 KB)

s1-eth4   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3a:93:8f:d3:07:0a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3893:8fff:fed3:70a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24305 (24.3 KB)  TX bytes:129143 (129.1 KB)

s1-eth5   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:0f:79:25:78:17  
          inet6 addr: fe80::80f:79ff:fe25:7817/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25551 (25.5 KB)  TX bytes:127465 (127.4 KB)

s2-eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9e:96:38:d2:34:03  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9c96:38ff:fed2:3403/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:126071 (126.0 KB)  TX bytes:26351 (26.3 KB)

s2-eth2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5a:fb:8a:b7:b7:24  
          inet6 addr: fe80::58fb:8aff:feb7:b724/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:149922 (149.9 KB)

s2-eth3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c6:2b:eb:d9:2f:d7  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c42b:ebff:fed9:2fd7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:150858 (150.8 KB)

s2-eth4   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:f5:87:f4:fd:99  
          inet6 addr: fe80::70f5:87ff:fef4:fd99/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:872 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:150174 (150.1 KB)

s2-eth5   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:45:73:53:cd:4e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d845:73ff:fe53:cd4e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:873 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:150516 (150.5 KB)

s2-eth6   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ae:7f:87:58:cb:95  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ac7f:87ff:fe58:cb95/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:151522 (151.5 KB)

s3-eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:d9:0d:21:e1:12  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d9:dff:fe21:e112/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:732 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:126873 (126.8 KB)  TX bytes:26921 (26.9 KB)

s3-eth2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:b5:31:10:93:e4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::50b5:31ff:fe10:93e4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:877 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:151616 (151.6 KB)

s3-eth3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9a:61:a2:cc:2f:ac  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9861:a2ff:fecc:2fac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:873 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:151004 (151.0 KB)

s3-eth4   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4a:be:3f:ef:41:0c  
          inet6 addr: fe80::48be:3fff:feef:410c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:151366 (151.3 KB)

s3-eth5   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c6:65:d5:c3:4a:10  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c465:d5ff:fec3:4a10/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152070 (152.0 KB)

s3-eth6   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:b3:6b:a2:6f:0c  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d8b3:6bff:fea2:6f0c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:881 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152984 (152.9 KB)

s4-eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 86:be:94:0d:d3:24  
          inet6 addr: fe80::84be:94ff:fe0d:d324/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:709 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:125363 (125.3 KB)  TX bytes:27595 (27.5 KB)

s4-eth2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6e:81:e3:26:5b:62  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6c81:e3ff:fe26:5b62/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:871 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:150852 (150.8 KB)

s4-eth3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c6:a7:d9:91:06:a1  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c4a7:d9ff:fe91:6a1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:877 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152420 (152.4 KB)

s4-eth4   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 66:13:80:61:af:c2  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6413:80ff:fe61:afc2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:871 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:738 (738.0 B)  TX bytes:151124 (151.1 KB)

s4-eth5   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:d2:7a:bb:25:c8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::74d2:7aff:febb:25c8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152294 (152.2 KB)

s4-eth6   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:d4:ef:4f:09:ba  
          inet6 addr: fe80::40d4:efff:fe4f:9ba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:875 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152240 (152.2 KB)

s4-eth7   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:32:4f:72:b3:ed  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1432:4fff:fe72:b3ed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152130 (152.1 KB)

s4-eth8   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:e2:6a:5c:56:49  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ece2:6aff:fe5c:5649/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:875 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152512 (152.5 KB)

s4-eth9   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 26:a8:9a:c7:51:bd  
          inet6 addr: fe80::24a8:9aff:fec7:51bd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:151918 (151.9 KB)

s4-eth10  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:fa:e6:5f:20:d5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::bcfa:e6ff:fe5f:20d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:877 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152632 (152.6 KB)

s4-eth11  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b6:06:34:c6:79:48  
          inet6 addr: fe80::b406:34ff:fec6:7948/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:871 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:151376 (151.3 KB)

s5-eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:05:3d:e5:42:48  
          inet6 addr: fe80::f005:3dff:fee5:4248/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:129143 (129.1 KB)  TX bytes:24305 (24.3 KB)

s6-eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:af:4c:06:07:27  
          inet6 addr: fe80::50af:4cff:fe06:727/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:127465 (127.4 KB)  TX bytes:25551 (25.5 KB)

s6-eth2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:54:88:74:e6:6d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1054:88ff:fe74:e66d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:857 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:150452 (150.4 KB)

s6-eth3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e2:f5:35:b9:e4:08  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e0f5:35ff:feb9:e408/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:858 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:150774 (150.7 KB)

s6-eth4   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c2:f4:84:7d:bc:a4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c0f4:84ff:fe7d:bca4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:151136 (151.1 KB)

s6-eth5   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d2:23:0b:30:1c:77  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d023:bff:fe30:1c77/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:860 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:150962 (150.9 KB)

s6-eth6   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:f0:05:6d:48:92  
          inet6 addr: fe80::74f0:5ff:fe6d:4892/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:862 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:152414 (152.4 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/a38896c254897e77b61a6b049a3c8007a1317a14/mininet/link.py#L280), it seems that mininet uses `tc` commands to set `packet loss`, `delay` etc. internally.

It tries to overwrite the qdisc file, therefore, it errors **`RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`**.

To set packet loss set it in `mininet` script itself by using `loss` parameter while creaqting a link. For an example see [this](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/simpleperf.py#L30).